# Is it possible to host a RabbitMQ Server publicly over the internet?

Tags: .net, messaging, rabbitmq

I need a Messaging system to be accessible to remote distributed clients over the Internet.
It needs to be secure and encrypted (SSL?).  Does RabbitMQ support this natively or will I need to use a WCF Wrapper? Both the Server and the Clients are .Net on Windows.

Comment: Hi Ravi - this was a while ago, but did you end up going with RabbitMQ for this implementation or something different? I have a similar problem only using Java and related technologies.

Comment: In this instance I used WCF with MSMQ binding.  But I have since, used rabbitmq for other applications and would recommend it.  In this context though, I would not be publicly exposing the rabbit server but would rather proxy it through a web service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RabbitMQ works on TCP, so it is certainly possible to expose it over the internet. It also [supports secure SSL connections](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html).

Comment: thanks. but it does seem open-ssl needs to be installed as an add-on in windows.

Comment: If open-ssl is a problem for you then set up a RabbitMQ server on Linux. You could even use a HyperV VM for that. Then when you need to scale beyond a single server for the MQ broker, you can just clone that HyperV VM onto multiple servers and set them up as a cluster.

Comment: P.S. on UNIX/Linux always use the latest binary installs from rabbitmq.com. Do not use their default package install because it is not mean for serious production use.

Comment: @driis, If the clients are in different platforms says iOS and android, what could be your answer? I can post that as a separate question, if you want. Thanks.